# Proving summation identities

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-verification

How would one go about proving the following identities?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n \frac{z_i}{z_i-z_j} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n \frac{z_i^2}{z_i-z_j} = (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n z_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n \frac{z_i^3}{z_i-z_j} = (n-1)\sum_{i=j}^n z_i^2+\sum_{i<j}^n z_i z_j$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n \frac{z_i^4}{z_i-z_j} = (n-1)\sum_{i=j}^n z_i^3+\sum_{i<j}^n z_i z_j(z_i+z_j)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n \frac{z_i^5}{z_i-z_j} = (n-1)\sum_{i=j}^n z_i^4+\sum_{i<j}^n z_i z_j(z_i^2+z_i z_j +z_j^2)$$

I see the obvious pattern here. The problem is that the algebra involving the summation is giving me some difficulty.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628258/general-identity-for-a-double-summation-theorem/628341#628341

Comment: What is $\large\left\{z_{i}\right\}$ ?.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i \neq j}^n \frac{z_i}{z_i-z_j}$
$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i \neq j}^n \left(1+\frac{z_j}{z_i-z_j} \right)=n(n-1)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i \neq j}^n \frac{z_j}{z_i-z_j}.
$

So the first equation proved.

You can now use the same strategy to split 
$
 \frac{z_i^2}{z_i-z_j}=\frac{(z_i^2-z_j^2)+z_j^2}{z_i-z_j}=(z_i+z_j)+\frac{z_j^2}{z_i-z_j}
$

on the second equation, so on and so forth.